# What is the point of (Lie) derivations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, intuition

Probably some very naive questions, but ...

**Definition**
Let $A$ be a vector space together with a bilinear map $\mu: A \times A \rightarrow A$.
We call a map $D: A \rightarrow A$ a *derivation* if it satisfies the Leibniz rule $D(\mu (a,b))=\mu(D(a), b) + \mu(a, D(b))$ for all $a,b \in A$. There are many examples of derivations, differential operators on a suitable associative algebra being one of them.

**Lie derivations**
One can look at derivations of Lie algebras (where $\mu$ is the Lie bracket).
Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (in fact any vector space with bilinear product) one can show that the derivations on $\mathfrak g$ form a Lie subalgebra of $End(\mathfrak g)$ with respect to the commutator. Furthermore, the Jacobi identity is precisely the statement that $ad_x$ is a derivation with respect to the Lie bracket for any $x \in\mathfrak g$.

**Question(s)**
Why should we care?
What is the relevance of Lie derivations? Why study them? What do they tell us about a Lie algebra? Are they somehow a generalization of differential operators? Are they related to the Lie algebra-Lie group correspondence? Is there any category theoretic perspective on them?

Comment: Lie algebra derivations are as important to Lie algebras as homomorphisms or automorphisms to groups. They tell us a lot about the Lie algebra, but not everything (have a look at the posts here).

Comment: For the link between  Lie algebra derivations and automorphisms see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574262/exponential-of-a-derivation-on-a-lie-algebra), and others.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The automorphism group of a Lie group $G$ is again a Lie group (how?). Its associated Lie algebra is the Lie algebra of derivations on the Lie algebra associated to $G$. Correct? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Furthermore derivations are $1$-cocycles for Lie algebra cohomology, and we can construct extensions with it. This also plays a role in geometry (your question is so broad, that it is difficult to mention all aspects).

Answer (score 0):

Well, one important application is building the tangent bundle of any finite dimensional manifolds in an intrinsic manner:

Extrinsically, that is assuming our manifold is embedded in some flat space, it turns out that a tangent vector of the manifold can be identified with a 'point' derivation and that their tangent fields can be identified with derivations. Now we can turn all of this around and define tangent vectors and hence tangent bundles and tangent fields for intrinsic manifolds, that is manifolds without an ambient embedding in a flat space.